# Unbounded (infinite) repetitions in transitions for covergroup bins

Tags: system-verilog

How can I define coverage bin for transition that might have many repetitions in it? What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
bins st = (2=> 3[* 1:$] => 2);
```

Of course, this doesn't work. Simulators give error messages when compiling this line.

Edit: Simulators complain about `$` symbol, they don't recognize it as "unbounded maximum". However when writing sequences, it is legal to use consecutive repetition operator as `[* 1:$]`. I hope next version of SystemVerilog makes it legal for covergroups too.

As a crude workaround, I substituted `$` with a large number so it works fine for my case.

```
bins st = (2=> 3[* 1:1000] => 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

SystemVerilog transition bins were not designed to handle anything but simple transitions. Anything more complex should be modeled using a `cover` directive, or some combination of *sequence*.`triggered`() method and `covergroup`.